# two form with same query but different return

Tags: forms, symfony

i have two Entitytype field in 2 different form

```
       ->add('idIndirizzo', EntityType::class, array(

                        'class' => 'AziendeBundle:anagrafica_indirizzo',
                        'query_builder' => function (anagrafica_indirizzoRepository $er )use($user) {
                            return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                                    ->where('u.idAnagrafica = ' . $user->getIdAnagrafica()->getId());
                        },
                        'choice_label' => function ($indirizzo) {
                            return $indirizzo->getVia() . ',' . $indirizzo->getNumero() . ',' . $indirizzo->getComune();
                        }
                    ))
```

in one form it work , in another form return me an error

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Form\Form2Type::AppBundle\Form\{closure}() must be an instance of AppBundle\Form\anagrafica_indirizzoRepository, instance of AziendeBundle\Repository\anagrafica_indirizzoRepository given
```

they are two different entity but there is in all two entity field idIndirizzo that is in relation with anagrafica_indirizzo field..

FORM 2

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $user = $options['user'];

        $builder
               ...


                  ->add('idIndirizzo', EntityType::class, array(

                        'class' => 'AziendeBundle:anagrafica_indirizzo',
  ERROR HERE--->>>                      'query_builder' => function (anagrafica_indirizzoRepository $er )use($user) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                                ->where('u.idAnagrafica = ' . $user->getIdAnagrafica()->getId());
                    },
                    'choice_label' => function ($indirizzo) {
                        return $indirizzo->getVia() . ',' . $indirizzo->getNumero() . ',' . $indirizzo->getComune();
                    }
                ))
                ...
    }
```

what difference can give this error??

Comment: Paste the second form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand my wrong ..

not used Repository

use AziendeBundle\Repository\anagrafica_indirizzoRepository;